# Authentication option by email address doesn't work, to deal with OpenID deprecation

Tags: support

Recent deprecation notice of OpenID has led me to create an email account

> YOUR ACTION IS NEEDED
>
> Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are ending
> support for third party OpenID providers. Your immediate action is
> needed in order for your account to stay active.
>
> Please click to add an email and password credential to your account.
>
> Alternately you can associate your account with Google or Facebook via
> the same link.
>
> OpenID will be no longer supported on July 25, 2018. If you haven’t
> updated your account before then you will lose access to your account.

My account is from my yahoo account as OpenID provider. When I type in my yahoo email address, I got the following error:

> This email is in use by a different account. To initiate a merge of multiple accounts, consult this help center article.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you already attached a new email login to your account 18 minutes ago. Are you sure you didn't try to double submit the form or something?

Comment: Do you mean I have successfully updated my account?

Comment: Yes, an email/password credential was created and attached to your account for your Yahoo address. Trying to add another one with the same email is going to indicate it's already used.